Why can't subprocess.Open find this executable (phantomjs)
[update]
I think the error message here is actually misleading. It turns out if I try to run the command phantomjs, I get an error:
-bash: /usr/bin/phantomjs: cannot execute: required file not found
I think that is a problem with the executable, and not that Popen can't find it.
I am trying to use selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS on a Raspberry Pi 5. This simple script
from selenium import webdriver

wd = webdriver.PhantomJS()

fails with this message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jkitchin/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1901, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'phantomjs'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jkitchin/bots/bibtex/pgs.py", line 3, in <module>
    wd = webdriver.PhantomJS()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jkitchin/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/jkitchin/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 79, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH. 

However, phantomjs is definitely in my path:
$ which phantomjs
/usr/bin/phantomjs

With these permissions:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 50179436 Oct 20 13:11 /usr/bin/phantomjs

I can run the command in a shell just fine.
this simpler script also fails:
import subprocess as sp
sp.run('phantomjs', capture_output=True)

Even using the full path leads to
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jkitchin/bots/bibtex/pgs.py", line 5, in <module>
    sp.run('/usr/bin/phantomjs', capture_output=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1901, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/phantomjs'

Any ideas on what is wrong here?
[update]
This python program:
import subprocess as sp
p = sp.run(['ls', '/usr/bin'], capture_output=True)
print('phantomjs' in p.stdout.decode('ascii'))

sp.run(['which', 'phantomjs'])
print()
sp.run(['file', '/usr/bin/phantomjs'])
print()
sp.run(['ls', '-al', '/usr/bin/phantomjs'])
print()
sp.run(['/usr/bin/phantomjs'])

Gives this output:
True
/usr/bin/phantomjs

/usr/bin/phantomjs: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=93e423f5359137d6cbb97c5e11aa34945e86e004, not stripped

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 50179436 Oct 20 13:11 /usr/bin/phantomjs

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jkitchin/bots/bibtex/pgs.py", line 14, in <module>
    sp.run(['/usr/bin/phantomjs'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1901, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/phantomjs'


What are the permissions on the /usr/bin directory itself?

Are you running this code as the same user that successfully ran the command directly?

I think so. at least when I use that command to print the env in it, I see my username, and the path directories where the command is.

The permissions on /usr/bin are drwxr-xr-x. It doesn't seem to matter where I put phantomjs, I tried a lot of places including /usr/local/bin, and in my home bin.

and, if I use another command in /usr/bin subprocess works fine.

Do you get a different result with os.system("/usr/bin/phantomjs") ?

How about print(os.listdir("/usr/bin")) ?

as myself, I see >>> print('phantomjs' in os.listdir("/usr/bin"))
True.
It seems even weirder, print(sp.run(['which', 'phantomjs'], capture_output=True)) finds it, but print(sp.run(['phantomjs'])) gives the no such file error.
